# Give an example of a positive function $f(n)$ which is neither $O(n^2)$ nor $\Omega(n^2)$

Tags: functions, algorithms

I am having trouble with this question as I don't know how to approach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to take $f(n)=n^{g(n)}$, where $g(n)$ is some bounded oscillatory function. What would be a good choice of $g(n)$ in this case?

Comment: would sinx be appropriate?

Comment: That's the idea, though you need to translate it because $n^{\sin n}=O(n)$. How about $g(n)=2+\sin(n)$?

Comment: i am not sure what you mean.

Comment: What I mean is that $n^{\sin n}$ won't work for your problem, but $n^{2+\sin n}$ will.

Comment: could you explain why you chose 2 + sinn? i appreciate the help.

Comment: We want the exponent to sometimes be bigger than $2$ (so the function is not $O(n^2)$) and sometimes smaller than $2$ (so the function is not $\Omega(n^2)$). $2+\sin n$ is an easy way to accomplish this. $\sin n$ on it's own won't work, because $\sin n\leq 1$.

Comment: why couldnt you use 1+sinn?

Comment: Because $1+\sin n\leq 2$. It's never larger than $2$.